# Dynamic Data Display in form with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Ok, in order to ask the question properly, I need to give a brief of what I am trying to achieve. So please bear with me.

I have a form that shows a drop down menu which fetches data from MySQL database.

[drop dpwn menu that fetches mysql data http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5378/59790538.png](http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/5378/59790538.png)

And my MySQL table looks like this:

[mysql table http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/2023/58196854.png](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/2023/58196854.png)

The piece of (junk) code that I am using to do this is as following:

```
<div class="rowElem">
<label for="service_name"><b>Particulars</b></label>
<?php 
            $sql1 = "select * from `service_tbl`";
            $query_result = mysql_query($sql1);

        echo "<select id='service_name' name='service_name'>";
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query_result ) ) {
            echo "<option value='".$row['id_service']."' >".$row['service_name']."</option>";
            $service_price = $row['service_price'];
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>
</div>

<div class="rowElem">
        <label for='service_price'><b>Price</b></label>
        <input type='text' id='service_price' name='service_price' value="<?php echo $service_price; ?>" />
</div>
```

And the code is doing what it's supposed to do:

[output http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6341/67345604.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/6341/67345604.png)

No matter which item I select, in the `Price` field of the form, I am getting the value `800` that was fetched at the end of the while loop. Which is the expected behavior according to the code.

But my objective is not being served by this. What I want is, to select an item from drop down menu and show it's corresponding price value in the `Price` field of the form. How do I do that? *I know my MySQL queries are deprecated and I should use **PDO** or **MySQLi** approach.* But that's not the main concern for me right now. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need some javascript for this.

Comment: Ajax is your answer ....or using query string if you can afford to have a page refresh

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
echo "<select id='service_name' name='service_name' onChange=\"document.getElementyById('service_price').value = this.value\">";
```

And remove this: `value="<?php echo $service_price; ?>"`

Answer (score 0):

It is showing the price of 800.00 since that is the last value that it gets from the query.  You can accomplish what you want by running a second query based on the selected service name.

```
$sql2 = " select service_price from service_tbl where id_service= $row['id_service']";
```

You would need to do this as an onchange event so it knows which value was selected from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty unclear what you are asking for here. As far as I can understand it, you want to change the price in the price field when an item is selected. If that is the case, you need to use javascript or jQuery.

Here is a solution with jQuery:

Something like this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#service_name',function(){
        $('#service_price').val(function(){
            return $(this).children('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('price');
        });
    });
});
```

***Furthermore, I must strongly advise you to move away from using the PHP `mysql_*` API as it has now been deprecated! Instead, use either PDO or mysqli, information for both can be found at the links below:***

1. [PDO Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
2. [MySQLi Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: This will print out the service id, but not the service price!

Comment: [JQuery is a Javascript framework, not a language all its own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490590/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-and-javascript).

Comment: If you don't point out that the OP should change markup, `data-price` will always be null. Plus the anonymous function you use as the `val()` argument is redundant - just setting the value will do.

Comment: @BenCarey The OP seems to be unfamiliar with JS, so don't do him a disservice by treating them as separate languages.  As written, it looks like you yourself don't know the difference, either.

Answer (score 0):

Granted that you generate such output:

```
<select id="service_name">
  <option value="1" data-price="80">Service #1</option>
  <option value="2" data-price="90">Service #2</option>
  ...
  <option value="n" data-price="100">Service #n</option>
</select>

<div id="price"></div>
```

You can do it with a little jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  var $priceDiv = $('#price');

  $('#service_name').change(function(){

    $priceDiv.html(

      $(this).children('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('price');

    );

  });

});
```